# psql can not access Postgres running in a Docker container

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, docker, port, psql

I have successfully built a [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)-based Docker [image that enables PostGIS](https://github.com/pamtrak06/postgis-pgrouting-osm):

The I run it:

```
docker run -d -t -p 5432:5432 -v ./data:/data --name postgis-osm-pgrouting -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres pamtrak06/postgis-pgrouting-osm bash
```

However, when I try to connect to the database via psql:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 postgres
```

I get an error:

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

I am a beginner with the port forwarding, but it looks like a port-related issue to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: The container should be able to start without a port forward, so I doubt that's the problem. Can you get access to the server log files?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `-t` flag  and the `bash` command from `docker run`?

Answer (score 2):

To access an application from within your container you need to first "attach" to that container.

You can do so by running the command:

```
docker exec -it container_name sh
```

What this command does is it runs the command `sh` inside the container `container_name`

It will prompt a shell terminal where you can now run your psql command like this:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Where here you're running psql with the user postgres (default authorized user for psql)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
docker run -d -t -p 5432:5432 -v $PWD/data:/data --name postgis-osm-pgrouting -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres pamtrak06/postgis-pgrouting-osm
```

and then

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 postgres
```

You've got:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "192.168.99.101" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

So apply [Configure PostgreSQL to accept TCP/IP connections][https://www.mozmorris.com/2011/11/15/configure-postgresql-to-accept-tcpip-connections.html], but not in production, for tests purpose only !

And override your Dockerfile with this configuration